# bash process substitution with tee dropping data

Tags: bash, pipe, file-descriptor, tee

I expect to see 1MiB in the wc's character count (which works at the bottom when 'tee' is writing to a file rather than a process substitution).
Is there something I'm missing about using process substitution with tee?

```
[192.168.20.40 (02b4b472) ~ 18:52:39]# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 | tee >(dd bs=1M count=1 | wc | sed 's/^/  /' > /dev/stderr) | wc
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
8192 bytes (8.2 kB, 8.0 KiB) copied, 0.00022373 s, 36.6 MB/s
        0       0    8192
      0       0   81920
[192.168.20.40 (02b4b472) ~ 18:52:56]# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 | tee /tmp/foo | wc
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0416881 s, 25.2 MB/s
      0       0 1048576
[192.168.20.40 (02b4b472) ~ 18:53:41]#
```

Using tee -p handles the stdout, but not the process substitution... which still comes up short.

```
[192.168.20.40 (02b4b472) ~ 19:17:05]# dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 | tee -p warn  >(dd bs=1M count=1 | wc | sed 's/^/  /' > /dev/stderr) | wc
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
8192 bytes (8.2 kB, 8.0 KiB) copied, 0.00084348 s, 9.7 MB/s
        0       0    8192
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.0417175 s, 25.1 MB/s
      0       0 1048576
[192.168.20.40 (02b4b472) ~ 19:18:25]#
```

Comment: try without `dd` in `>()`: `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1 | tee >(wc | sed 's/^/   /' 1>&2) | wc`

Comment: Or with `>(dd bs=1M count=1 iflag=fullblock | ...)`. Or without count: `>(dd bs=1M | wc | sed '' >&2)`